# Far jumping causes triple fault after PMode is enabled?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, osdev

This stage of my bootloader is loaded at `0x7e0:0x0000`. After some "debugging" I've discovered that the following code generates a triple fault after my **far jump**. If I move the hang (Yes, including the actual procedure itself) before the jump, it doesn't triple fault. Sorry I couldn't include less code. I'm just trying to make sure I'm providing enough code so the bug isn't missed.

Here's my code:

```
bits 16

jmp SetUpPMode

GTDData:
    dd 0
    dd 0
    ;Code Descriptor
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
    ;Data Descriptor
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
GTDEnd:

GDTPointer:
    dw (GTDEnd - GTDData) - 1
    dd GTDData

LoadGDT:
    lgdt [GDTPointer]
    ret

SetUpPMode:
    cli
    mov ax, 0x7E0
    mov ds, ax

    call LoadGDT

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp 0x8:main

bits 32

main:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov esp, 0x90000

    jmp hang

hang:
    ;cli
    hlt
    jmp hang
```

I bet the bug/error is blatantly obvious, but I just can't seem to find it. Could someone please point it out? (If it matters, I'm using Virtual Box)

Comment: You should use CLI once at the start of your program and never use STI until you've setup a proper protected mode IDT. There's also no point in putting PUSHA/POPA around LGDT since it doesn't change any of the registers saved and restored by those instructions.

Comment: @RossRidge I cleared up all the `sti`s and `cli`s, but it still triple faults. I don't really think your comment was intended as an answer, but I thought I might as well inform you.

Comment: One problem is that the offset of `main` in your code doesn't match the offset of main relative the protected mode code segment. In your code its offset is something like 0x00xx, but relative to the protected mode code segment its offset would be 0x00007exx. You either need to adjust your code segment base or the ORG of your program (eg. so it loads at 0000:7e00 instead of 07e0:0000)

Comment: @RossRidge Yep, that was indeed the problem. Thank you for the tips and help.

Comment: On top of all the real problems in your code that were mentioned, I hope that you enabled the A20 line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You load the code and the data at `0x07E0:0x0000`. Therefore, all the references that the assembler and linker make are based at `0x07E0:0x0000` - such as `main`, which may be `0x0020` or something.

But your GDT has the Code Segment based to `0x00000000` - so the `jmp 0x8:main` would `JMP` to absolute address `0x00000020` or something - nowhere near where the code is at `0x00007E20` or wherever. Either change the base of the segments in the GDT, or change the code to work from a real mode segment of `0x0000`.

Comment: I fiddled with the `org` and the segments for a little bit and it stopped triple faulting. The problem has been fixed.